# Task.WhenAll result ordering

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I understand from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh556530(v=vs.140)) that the task execution order for `Task.WhenAll` is not deterministic but I cannot find any information about result order.

Will the results collection contain the results in the order in which the tasks where ordered in the input or the results can be in any order?

From the tests that I did, it seems to keep the order but I need a confirmation.

Comment: *"the task execution order for `Task.WhenAll` is not deterministic"* -- This statement can be misleading. The `Task.WhenAll` does not execute any task. It merely *waits* for the completion of the tasks. It doesn't affect their execution to the slightest.

Answer (score 122):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194766%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Task.WhenAll<TResult>(IEnumerable<Task<TResult>>)
```

The overloads which take `Task<TResult>` as inputs contain this statement:

> If none of the tasks faulted and none of the tasks were canceled, the
> resulting task will end in the RanToCompletion state. The Result of
> the returned task will be set to an array containing all of the
> results of the supplied tasks **in the same order as they were provided**
> (e.g. if the input tasks array contained t1, t2, t3, the output task's
> Result will return an TResult[] where arr[0] == t1.Result, arr[1] ==
> t2.Result, and arr[2] == t3.Result).

Comment: Just to be clear for people reading this like me, the overload `Task.WhenAll<TResult> Method (Task<TResult>[])` also contains the same statement.

Comment: Because arrays are IEnumerable.

Comment: `This is the only overload of the four which contains this statement` -> This is because the non generic form of Task.WehAll() returns a task which returns void so there is no resulting array.