# Task.WhenAll<TResult[]> Return Order?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-t

I have a series of long-running functions which each return a string. I feel this would be something ideal for a Task, and I got excited when I saw the `Task.WhenAll<TResult[]>` function, but I fear it may have been short lived; given the... asynchronous nature of `async` and `await`, and that my requirements are that the values within this array be in a very specific order, I need to know:
if I await this `Task.WhenAll<T[]>(...)`, will the resultant array be populated in the order of which the consumed enumerable of `Task<T>` were called, or the order in which they were completed?

### EDIT

I see this question is an exact duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175611/task-whenall-result-ordering) question asked a year ago. The answer to the question is also found there, though I will also post it here such to give it better coverage.

Answer (score 1):

As [Yuval](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870803/yuval-itzchakov) stated in his answer to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175611/task-whenall-result-ordering), the answer is provided by the MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194766%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For brevity;

The answer is that the array will be populated in the order which the Tasks were added to the `IEnumerable<Task<T>>` collection that was passed to `Task.WhenAll(...)`, ***NOT*** the order in which they were completed.

Comment: Your interpretation is incorrect, the order is **the order they where passed in to the function**. The order they are awaited or completed has no effect on it.

Comment: So the order in which they were called, not the order completed; right, got it; edited.

Comment: No, not the order they where called either. It is the order they where in in the `IEnumerable<Task<T>>` you passed in to `Task.WhenAll`. I can to `Task<Foo> t1 = GetFooAsync(); Task<Foo> t2 = GetFooAsync(); var result = await Task.WhenAll(new[] {t2, t1});`, that will have `result[0] == t2.Result` and `result[1] == t1.Result` even though `t1` was called first. All that mattes is the order they where passed in to `WhenAll`