# C#/Tasks/await whenAll(): Better solution than relying on response/request list?

Tags: c#, loops, task

I am looking for a better solution for the following case. Currently I am relying on the same order of the two lists in the following example.

In .NET Core/C# I am using a SDK that performs REST calls under the hood. The post method is async.
The code looks like that:

```
var requestTasks = new List<Task<SdkResponseType>>();
foreach (SdkRequest request in requests)
{
    requestTasks.Add(sdkClient.PostAsync(request);
}

var responses = await Task.WhenAll(requestTasks);
```

After that I want to update the DB with the values of the response.
I know that the order of responses fits to the order of requests (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175611/task-whenall-result-ordering)).

Unfortunately, the response objects does not contain a value that gives me a hint to the entry request list.
It feels ugly to rely on the same order of responses and requests. Is there a better solution that does not contain patching the SDK?

I think, I am surely missing some code pattern.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
var taskList = emailOperatableCollection.MailjetQueue
    .Select( async emailOperatable => {
        var request = CreateMailJetRequest(emailOperatable,authUseraccount);
        return  new {
           Request = request,
           Result = await sdkClient.PostAsync(request)
        };
     } );    
var responses = await Task.WhenAll(taskList);

foreach(var response in responses){
    var originalRequest = response.Request;
    var result = response.Result;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Maybe, I do not understand your example correctly, but the compiler says that async does not exist in the current context.

Comment: What is type of requests? You can try `requests.ToList().Select` let me know if it does not work.

Comment: See concrete code below. The request is an object from the Mailjet SDK.

Answer (score 0):

@Akash Kava: I think it's easer, not to discuss on my pseudo code above. This is method with the foreach with an async. The request is an object from the Mailjet SDK.

```
    private async void SendEmailCollectionAsync(EmailOperatableCollection emailOperatableCollection, AuthUseraccount authUseraccount)
    {
        var mailjetClient = new MailjetClient(RuntimeEnvironment.BroadcastAdapterMailMailjetPublicKey, RuntimeEnvironment.BroadcastAdapterMailMailjetPrivateKey);
        var mailjetRequestTasks = new List<Task<MailjetResponse>>();

        foreach (EmailOperatable emailOperatable in emailOperatableCollection.MailjetQueue)
        {
            var request = CreateMailjetRequest(emailOperatable, authUseraccount);
            mailjetRequestTasks.Add(mailjetClient.PostAsync(request));
        }

        var mailjetResponses = await Task.WhenAll(mailjetRequestTasks);
    }
```

Now I want every response in the the array mailjetResponses to be assigned to every emailOperatable in the List emailOperatableCollection.MailjetQueue.